# Error en Laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo el siguiente error al editar un registro NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
 este es el codigo

```
Route::get('/ficha/editar/{id}', 'fichaController@editarficha');

Route::post('/ficha/edit/{id}', 'fichaController@editficha' );
```

en el controlador

```
public function editarficha($id)
{

    $var = ficha::where('id', $id)->first();
    return view('edip',['var'=>$var]);


}


public function editficha(Request $request, $id)
{

    $nuevoApellido=$request->input('apellido');
    $nuevoNombre=$request->input('nombre');
    $nuevoDNI=$request->input('dni');
    $nuevoEcivil=$request->input('ecivil');
    $nuevoNacional=$request->input('nacional');
    $nuevoFnaci=$request->input('fnaci');
    $nuevoEdad=$request->input('edad');
    $nuevoFingreso=$request->input('fingreso');

     $var= ficha::find($id);

          $var->apellido = $nuevoApellido;
          $var->nombre = $nuevoNombre;
          $var->dni = $nuevoDNI;
          $var->ecivil = $nuevoEcivil;
          $var->nacional = $nuevoNacional;
          $var->fnaci = $nuevoFnaci;
          $var->edad = $nuevoEdad;
          $var->fingreso = $nuevoFingreso;
          $var->save();
          return view('edip'); 



}
```

y el formulario de carga

```
<form action="edit/{id}" method="post">

                {{ csrf_field() }}



                    <div class="col-md-6">

                       <div class="form-group"> 
                          <label for="nombre">Apellido</label> 
                          <input type="text" name="apellido" class="form-control" value="{{$var->apellido}} ">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="nombre">Nombre</label> 
                          <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" value="{{$var->nombre}} ">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="nombre">D.N.I</label> 
                          <input type="text" name="dni" class="form-control" value="{{$var->dni}} ">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="nombre">Estado Civil</label> 
                          <input type="text" name="ecivil" class="form-control" value="{{$var->ecivil}} ">
                        </div>



                   </div>



                    <div class="col-md-6">

                       <div class="form-group"> 
                          <label for="nombre">Nacionalidad</label> 
                          <input type="text" name="nacional" class="form-control" value="{{$var->nacional}} ">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="nombre">Fecha de Nacimiento</label> 
                          <input type="text" name="fnaci" class="form-control" value="{{$var->fnaci}} ">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="nombre">Edad</label> 
                          <input type="text" name="edad" class="form-control" value="{{$var->edad}} ">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="nombre">Fecha Ingreso</label> 
                          <input type="text" name="fingreso" class="form-control" value="{{$var->fingreso}} ">
                        </div>






                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group text-right" > 
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                        </div> 

                   </form>
```

Comment: El error esta directamente en tu archivo de rutas, ensaya con una ruta a la vez para saber en cual de las dos esta el error, comprueba el nombre de tu controlador y de la función que llama cada ruta, comprueba la ruta a la que estas tratande de acceder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error puede ser que en el formulario estas llamando en action la ruta "edit/{id"

```
<form action="edit/{id}" method="post">
```

Mientras que en tu archivos de rutas lo defines como Route::post('/ficha/edit/{id}', 'fichaController@editficha' );

```
Route::post('/ficha/edit/{id}', 'fichaController@editficha' );
```

Ensaya con eso

Answer (score 0):

Revisa el nombre de la ruta para la acción del formulario, para ello puedes usar el comando

```
php artisan route:list
```

en caso que tu ruta por algún motivo no tenga nombre y no la puedas llamar

```
Route::get('/ficha/editar/{id}', 'fichaController@editarficha')->name('mi.ruta');
```